# How to intent from FRAGMENT to FRAGMENT?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

Im trying to Intent from fragment to fragment and here is my code..

```
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_add_place:

            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AddPlacesMapFragment());
   ft.commit();
            }


            return true;
        }
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@id/maplayout" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/buttonResetPins"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the log trace

```
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749): No view found for id 0x7f060005 (com.c4a.itravellipaph:id/maplayout) for fragment AddPlacesMapFragment{4322dc18 #1 id=0x7f060005}
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749): Activity state:
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749):   Local Activity 4201c1c0 State:
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749):     mResumed=true mStopped=false mFinished=false
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749):     mLoadersStarted=true
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749):     mChangingConfigurations=false
01-15 15:23:33.268: E/FragmentManager(19749):     mCurrentConfig={1024 0 1.0 515mcc2mnc en_PH
```

how to call my other fragment? Big thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
   FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AddPlacesMapFragment());
   ft.commit();
```

That should do it!

Comment: This is correct. Sorry, I read the question wrong - my answer is if you wanted to pass data to your fragment.

Comment: No i just want to intent from current fragment to the next fragment

Comment: @AndroidNewbie You need to replace R.id.fragment_container with the id of your Frame Layout/Fragment defined in XML !

Comment: Ooh ok, i guess your targeting Android 3.0 and above. Updated my code

Comment: this "R.id.fragment_container" is this the id of the XML layout?